# How to rewrite /index.php to /app.php

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this in my `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

It rewrites both, `http://www.site` to `http://site`, and `site` to `site/app.php`
I also want to rewrite `site/index.php` to `site/app.php`.
How can I do it?
When I request `/index.php` I get a 404 response.

I've tried to rename `app_dev.php` to `index.php` en my local host, but doesn't work. I've done the next change in `.htaccess`:

```
order allow,deny
allow from all
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  #   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app_dev.php [QSA,L]   #line deleted
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [QSA,L]         #line added
</IfModule>
```

and rename the file `app_dev.php` to `index.php`

Comment: It's not clear in your question what you want the URL bar to look like and which file you want to be processed.  Could you also add what currently happens when you request `/index.php`?

Comment: Why not rename app.php to index.php?

Comment: I don't know the reason why Symfony use this name, I'd prefer not to change what is working fine. Just want to do that rule. Is it possible?

Comment: yes I think you should use the permanent redirect for the URL. try that hope that should work for you.

Comment: How would you do it? With this? `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [R=301,L]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How would you do it? With this? RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^index.php$ [NC] RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [R=301,L]?

No, something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php$ / [R=301,L]
```

And you don't want to change the app.php line to index.php, assuming that you're getting a 404 because `index.php` isn't there, you don't want to be rewriting things *to* something that isn't there.

Comment: Ok, but where to add this line? I've tried it without success. Same response.

Comment: @ManoloSalsas to the top